# Parse Error - Syntax Error

Tags: php, syntax-error

I am trying to install a PHP script and almost had it installed but the final step of the installation gave me a blank white page with the following error message:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in /home/user/public_html/install/step5.php on line 83

This is line 81, 82 and 83...As you can see, line 83 does not even have much there, yet it produces the above error:

```
require_once( '../vars.php' );
mysql_query( 'SHOW TABLES' );
$res = ;
```

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 2):

```
$res = ;
```

is not valid syntax. You need to set `$res` to be equal to something.

Comment: What do you mean to be equal to something?

Comment: @user2056144: For example, `$res = 2;` or `$res = "hello";`. What is that line supposed to be doing? (I'm guessing that you didn't write this code? You might want to get a "refund")

Comment: No, I didn't write it. It came like this. That is why I am stuck. LOL.

Comment: @user2056144 Whoever gave it to you gave you incomplete code. Basically, whoever was writing that line left out the second half of it (as though they were interrupted halfway). There's nothing anyone on StackOverflow can do to help (at least not with these three lines of code alone)- go to whoever you got it from and ask them.

Comment: Well, thanks for trying to help me.